# Kyronet & androidstudio - timed out during TCP registration

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, server, kryonet

I'm trying to connect to my server created in kryonet. So running server in eclipse and then connecting in android studio.

I get this weird error.

**Server:**

```
package server;


import java.io.IOException;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
//import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;
import server.SomeRequest;
import server.SomeResponse;
import common.Network;

public class GameServer extends ApplicationAdapter {

static int SERVER_TCP_PORT;
static int SERVER_UDP_PORT;

Server server;

public GameServer () throws IOException {


    server = new Server();
    server.start();

    Kryo kryo = server.getKryo();
    kryo.register(SomeRequest.class);
    kryo.register(SomeResponse.class);

    //server.bind(54555, 54777);
    server.bind(54557);
    System.out.println("Started server!");
    server.addListener(new Listener() {
        public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
           if (object instanceof SomeRequest) {
              SomeRequest request = (SomeRequest)object;
              System.out.println(request.text);

              SomeResponse response = new SomeResponse();
              response.text = "Thanks";
              connection.sendTCP(response);
           }
        }
    });
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //SERVER_TCP_PORT = Network.SERVER_TCP_PORT;
    //SERVER_UDP_PORT = Network.SERVER_UDP_PORT;

    new GameServer();
}
}
```

**Client:**

```
package com.mygdx.game.android;

import android.util.Log;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;

/**
 * Created by 112944 on 25.1.2016.
 */
public class Connect extends Game{

private SomeRequest request;
private SomeResponse response;
private Client client;

private String ipAddress;
private int tcpPort, udpPort;

@Override
public void create() {
    connectToServer();

}
public void render() {
    super.render(); //important!
}
public void dispose() {

}
public void connectToServer(){

    client = new Client();
    client.start();

    InetAddress address = client.discoverHost(54777, 5000);
    Log.w("address", String.valueOf(address));

    Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
    kryo.register(SomeRequest.class);
    kryo.register(SomeResponse.class);


    Log.w("here", "yeah");
    try {
        //client.connect(50000, "10.0.2.2", 54557, 54777);
        client.connect(5000, "10.0.2.2", 54557);// 10.0.2.2 is addres for connecting localhost from emulator.
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.w("expection",e);

    }
    request = new SomeRequest();
    request.text = "Here is the request";
    client.sendTCP(request);

    client.addListener(new Listener() {
        public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
            if (object instanceof SomeResponse) {
                response = (SomeResponse) object;
                Log.w("response",response.text);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Error:**

```
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connected, but timed out during TCP registration.
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection: Note: Client#update must be called in a separate thread during connect.
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection:     at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:161)
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection:     at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.connect(Client.java:104)
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection:     at com.mygdx.game.android.Connect.connectToServer(Connect.java:53)
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection:     at com.mygdx.game.android.Connect.create(Connect.java:28)
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:243)
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519)
01-25 14:12:56.986 25060-25083/com.mygdx.game.android W/expection:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
01-25 14:14:50.531 25060-25066/com.mygdx.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.564ms
```

I've been trying to do everything with no luck.

**depencies:**

> > kryo 3.0.3
> >     kryonet 2.21
> >     objenesis-2.1
> >     reflectasm-1.10.1-shaded
> >     minlog-1.3.0
> >     gdx-1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to connect the client in different thread

I edit your connectToServer method. try it

```
public void connectToServer(){

client = new Client();
client.start();

InetAddress address = client.discoverHost(54777, 5000);
Log.w("address", String.valueOf(address));

Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
kryo.register(SomeRequest.class);
kryo.register(SomeResponse.class);

request = new SomeRequest();
request.text = "Here is the request";    

client.addListener(new Listener() {
    public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
        if (object instanceof SomeResponse) {
            response = (SomeResponse) object;
            Log.w("response",response.text);
        }
    }
});

new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        Log.w("here", "yeah");
        try {
            //client.connect(50000, "10.0.2.2", 54557, 54777);
            client.connect(5000, "10.0.2.2", 54557);// 10.0.2.2 is addres for connecting localhost from emulator.
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.w("expection",e);

        }
    }
}.start();        

client.sendTCP(request);}
```